# Returning value or object from Firebase cloud function is always null

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using the below code to return an object from Firebase, but the value is always null.

This is my Firebase cloud function:

```
exports.useVoucher = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const type = data.type
    const voucher_code = data.voucher_code
    const current_time = data.current_time
    console.log("useVoucher type is ", type + " and voucher_code is ", voucher_code)
    return admin.database().ref().child("vouchers").child(voucher_code).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log("useVoucher snapshot is ", snapshot.val());
            if (snapshot.val()[type] === true) {
                let path = "vouchers/" + voucher_code + "/" + type
                admin.database().ref().update({
                    [[path]]: current_time
                }, error => {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log("useVoucher failed")
                        return {is_valid: false}
                    } else {
                        console.log("useVoucher succeeded")
                        return {is_valid: true}
                    }
                })
            } else {
                console.log("useVoucher voucher found but type not found or not true")
                        return {is_valid: false}
            }
        } else {
            console.log("useVoucher voucher_code is not valid");
                        return {is_valid: false}
        }
    })
})
```

And this is how I call it client side (I removed some irrelevant code):

```
async function testVoucher(type) {
    const voucher_code = input_text.value.trim()
    console.log("submitVoucher voucher_code is ", voucher_code + " type is ", type)
    let current_time = Number(new Date())
    console.log("submitVoucher current_time is ", current_time)
    await useVoucher({ type: type, voucher_code: voucher_code, current_time: current_time })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("submitVoucher res is ", res)
            let data = res.data
            console.log("submitVoucher data is ", data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("submitVoucher error is ", error)
        })
}
```

Regardless of which path the cloud function takes, it always returns "res is null." Why is that?

Comment: In that last snippet (and in general) don't combine `await` and `then` please. Use one or the other.

Comment: What log output do you get from the Cloud Function, and from the client? Can you add those to your quesiton?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Why can't you combine them?

Answer (score 1):

There are two potential reasons for your problem:

1. You don't [chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining) the Promises. More precisely you don't return the Promise returned by `admin.database().ref().update(...);`. You should have a `return` in front of this line.
2. In case the update is successful you actually don't return anything. As a matter of fact, even by adding `return` in front of this line you would only return something **in case of error** and nothing in case of success: `admin.database().ref().update({...}, error => { **You only return here**})`.

Since you use several `if` blocks, it is easier to use async/await. The following should do the trick (untested):

```
exports.useVoucher = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {   // See async keyword

    try {
        const type = data.type
        const voucher_code = data.voucher_code
        const current_time = data.current_time
        console.log("useVoucher type is ", type + " and voucher_code is ", voucher_code)

        const snapshot = await admin.database().ref().child("vouchers").child(voucher_code).get();
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            console.log("useVoucher snapshot is ", snapshot.val());
            if (snapshot.val()[type] === true) {
                let path = "vouchers/" + voucher_code + "/" + type
                await admin.database().ref().update({
                    [[path]]: current_time
                });
                return { is_valid: true }
            } else {
                console.log("useVoucher voucher found but type not found or not true")
                return { is_valid: false }
            }
        } else {
            console.log("useVoucher voucher_code is not valid");
            return { is_valid: false }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        // Important: Look in the doc how to deal with an error in a Callable Cloud Function.
        //https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }

});
```

---

Note that we use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.Reference#get) method. `once("value")` is correct but using `get()` is clearer and more readable (`get()` has also some other advantages for the Client SDK, see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try by wrapping your cloud function in promise to return callback of resolve and reject when your execution gets completed.

```js
exports.useVoucher = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const type = data.type
    const voucher_code = data.voucher_code
    const current_time = data.current_time
    console.log("useVoucher type is ", type + " and voucher_code is ", voucher_code)
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        admin.database().ref().child("vouchers").child(voucher_code).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                console.log("useVoucher snapshot is ", snapshot.val());
                if (snapshot.val()[type] === true) {
                    let path = "vouchers/" + voucher_code + "/" + type
                    admin.database().ref().update({
                        [[path]]: current_time
                    }, error => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log("useVoucher failed")
                            reject({ is_valid: false })
                        } else {
                            console.log("useVoucher succeeded")
                            resolve({ is_valid: true })
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    console.log("useVoucher voucher found but type not found or not true")
                    reject({ is_valid: false })
                }
            } else {
                console.log("useVoucher voucher_code is not valid");
                reject({ is_valid: false })
            }
        })
    }
    
})
```

Comment: It should not be needed to return a custom `Promise` here. The `once()` call already returns a promise, so OP should be able to bubble up their result.